# When I click the button in my form, I expect it to execute this post function in my view, but it doesn't

Tags: django, forms, post

The form

```
<form action="{% url 'add-coupon' %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="coupon">
 <input id="coupon_code" class="input-text" name="coupon" value="" placeholder="ENTER COUPON CODE" type="text">
 </div>
 <button class="tp-btn-h1" type="submit">Apply coupon</button>
</form>
```

My Url

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AddToCart, CartItems, AddCoupon

urlpatterns = [    
    path('add-coupon/', AddCoupon.as_view(), name='add-coupon'),
]
```

The Views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib import messages
from .carts import Cart
from .models import Coupon
from app.models import Product

class AddCoupon(generic.View):
    print("I should see two statements below this")
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Button Works")
        print(messages.success(self.request, "Your coupon has been included successfully")
```

When I click the button, I should get all the 3 statements but I only get ( I should see two statements below this ), So the function is not executing and I don't know why. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: The print in the `class` is done when it creates the class, so the first time the file is interpreted.

Comment: Could you update your question?: 1. The title should be a *title*, e.g.: "View's post method seems not to be run in django-form". 2. The sentence: "...I should get all the 3 statements but I only get " (...) seems to be uncomplete. What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

1. The template and the view looks ok. You could a debugger if breakpoint (e.g.: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) in the view's `post` method to see if it's executed.
2. As @willem-van-onsem said, the `print` after the class header is run only when the class definition is read, and this is at import time.
3. messages.success(...) is used to generate messages for the user which will be displayed in the next page the user loads. In my tests, this returns None.
4. Use logging module to get output which can be logged to the console or log file, e.g.:

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AddCoupon(generic.View):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        log.info("Button Works")
        messages.success(self.request, "Your coupon has been included successfully.")
```

Comment: Hey, ok, so just forget the print messages, the whole idea was to get the function executing but even after logging, nothing shows up on console, I am not even getting the pdb_setrace() output.

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to resort to a function based view and it worked. The class view also works on another project, so I don't really know what's the issue, but the function based view did cut it for this one. Thanks

Comment: It actually failed again after one response. This is crazy!